# How can I match a function parameter of a given type, regardless of whether it's passed by value, reference or pointer?

Tags: clang, llvm, abstract-syntax-tree

Here's a clang AST matcher which will match a function any of whose parameters are a `std::vector` (of any type) passed by value or reference:

```cpp
DeclarationMatcher funcMatcher = functionDecl(
    anyOf(hasAnyParameter(
              hasType(references(recordDecl(matchesName("std::vector"))))),
          hasAnyParameter(hasType(recordDecl(matchesName("std::vector"))))));
```

I'd like to know if there is some matcher which will match e.g. `std::vector&`, `std::vector*` *and* `std::vector`?

Obviously I could expand the matcher above for the pointer case, but I was wondering if clang AST has some concept of the 'underlying' type. I've spent quite a bit of time looking [here](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/LibASTMatchersReference.html).